# Eclipse+PyDev: pydev can't find django.contrib.messages

Tags: django, eclipse, interpreter, pydev, message

When, from Eclipse, i run my django project, it throws

> ImportError django.contrib.messages: No module named messages

Furthermore, in django consolle `import django.contrib` works fine, it throws

> ImportError: No module named messages

Why? 
In my django folder, where the python interpreter of pydev points, there is ./contrib/messages folder, so i don't understand why it can't find django.contrib.messages

Comment: The problem si that python points to other django version.Infact django.VERSION, in python consolle, print (1, 1, 1, 'final', 0). Now i try to change django version pointed by python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved deleting old version of django that was in */usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/*
and reinstalling django.